# how to fix application error on heroku when i deploy react app along with json-server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, json-server

I have been trying out json server along with react but for some reason I keep getting application error on Heroku. is it alright to use json-server  for testing purposes.i have shared my server.js, file structure and package.json

server.js

```
    const jsonServer = require('json-server');
    const app = jsonServer.create();
    const path = require('path');
    const express = require('express');
    // const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
    const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
    
    **app.use('/data', router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
    app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });**
    
    server.listen(port);
```

my folder structure

```
----client
    ----node modules
    ----public
    ----src
    ----packgage.json
----db.json
----packgae.json
----server.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "music",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run json-server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: i think *build* script is missing in *package.json*     https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1557

Comment: I have added heroku-postbuild script in my package.json. the article which you sent says  if heroku-postbuild script is included, it will be run instead of the build script.

Comment: what does `npm run build` do then

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app.use(express.static('client/build')));
    app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client','build', 'index.html'));
    });
```

and in ur package.json change to this

```
"heroku_postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).